# What happens if we try to define the Lebesgue integral by an infimum?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ denote a measure space. Then each measureable function $f : X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ has a Lebesgue integral $\int f d\mu$ given by take a supremum of the integrals of simple functions that are bounded above by $f$.

> **Question.** Suppose we instead try taking infima of simple functions that are bounded below by $f$. I assume the resulting integral is "poorly behaved", since no one ever talks about it. My question is quite simply, what happens if we do this?

Comment: Actually I think that the resulting integral is the same integral. Let $f$ be any bounded function (say $0 \le f < M$), and consider the function $g(x) =M-f(x)$. Then you calculate the integral of $g$ using supremum, meaning that you are calculating the integral of $f$ using infimum.

Comment: Excellent question, I've been wondering the same! This would allow one to have more control over the approximations given by simple functions, which would be useful.

Comment: @Crostul That works only if $X$ has finite measure. Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, with the Lebesgue measure. Every simple function $\geqslant f$ must attain a strictly positive value on a set of infinite measure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)= x^{-\frac12}$ on $(0,1)$.
Note that the function values can be arbitrarily large.

Since a simple function takes only finitely many values, every simple function that is bounded below by $f$ has to be infinite on a set of non-zero measure.

Thus, the integral using your suggested infimum definition would be $\infty$,
whereas the usual Lebesgue integral would have a finite value.

This is just an example, but it demonstrates the difficulty that will arise with non-bounded functions.
For bounded functions $f$ your infimum definition is equivalent to the usual defintion, see the comment of Crostul.

Comment: Adding to your answer (giving a more heuristic perpsective): It is more reasonable to bound **numbers** from above (with generalised numbers), than it is to bound **generalised numbers** from below (with numbers).

Comment: What if we expand the class of simple functions so as to include countable-linear combinations? Do you know if the $\sup$ and $\inf$ definitions become equivalent in that case?

Comment: @goblin then how you add them up will start to matter. So it is very messy!